# Binding ListView Visibility when DataContext is a CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm new to the world of WPF and I am constantly asking myself 'am I doing this right?'.  My current scenario involves binding the Visibility of a ListView based on the state of a collection.  I have the Converter worked out fine, my issue/question is how to best declare the XAML to setup the binding.

First off, I have a `CollectionViewSource`, which is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of View Models:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" />
```

Next, I have declared my `ListView` as follows:

```
<ListView DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

The code for my Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null && (value is ICollection && (value as ICollection).Count > 0))
            return Visibility.Visible;

    return Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

I've come up with two ways to setup the binding so that it actually works:

The first:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=SourceCollection, 
  Converter={StaticResource ListToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

The second:

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
  Path=DataContext.Source,
  Converter={StaticResource ListToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

In the second scenario, the Convert method is called twice, and I'm not sure why... This leads me to believe that this is not the 'right' way.

Lastly, I also tried setting the path as `Path=Source` and `Path=DataContext.Source` but those fail with these errors at runtime (respectively):

> BindingExpression path error: 'DataContext' property not found on
>    'object' ''ListCollectionView' BindingExpression path error: 'Source'
>   property not found on 'object' ''ListCollectionView'

I was under the impression that when I set the DataContext of the ListView to be a CollectionViewSource, I should be able to access its properties (e.g. `Source`).  Why am I required to add the `RelativeSource` here?

There are a series of sub-questions in here and I fully realize that.  As such, answering just a few or giving some pointers is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind to certain properties on objects which provide items you need to set [`BindsDirectlyToSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.bindsdirectlytosource.aspx) to `true` in the binding.

Comment: Thanks for providing this link.  While it was an optional solution, I ended up just Binding directly to the Collection in the ViewModel instead of the CollectionViewSource as I was having difficulty with change notification.